# How do I make a reload timer for my player's weapon in pygame?

Tags: python, timer, pygame

So I'm making a top down shooter, left click shoots, right click reloads the gun. I want to make it so the player can't shoot while reloading and I don't want the screen to show that the player has full ammo until AFTER they have fully reloaded (just like any fps game). Does anyone know how I can implement this? Thanks for any feedback :)

Here's my mouse / firing code:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (1, 0, 0) and ammo > 0:
    ammo -= 1
    bullet = Bullet()
    all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
    bullet_list.add(bullet)
elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (0, 0, 1):
    pygame.time.wait(1000)
    ammo = full_ammo
```

So I know the `pygame.time.wait(1000)` freezes the whole program for an entire second, I had it in there thinking it would delay setting the `ammo = full_ammo` but it pauses the whole game haha. Does anyone know of a function or `pygame.` whatever function that I can use to delay setting the ammo to full (simulating a reload time)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add a variable that keeps track of whether you are reloading at the moment and at what time you last reloaded. That would look somewhat like this:

```
elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (0, 0, 1):
    lastReloadTime = time.clock()
    reloading = True
    ammo = full_ammo
```

(Keep in mind you'll need to `import time`)

Then, you'll need to update your shooting code to add a condition to see if you're reloading at the moment or not.

```
if not reloading and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (1, 0, 0) and ammo > 0:
    ammo -= 1
    bullet = Bullet()
    all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
    bullet_list.add(bullet)
```

Then lastly, you'll need to add some code to see if you are done reloading or not. This should be outside of your event handling.

```
if reloading and time.clock() - lastReloadTime > TIME_TO_RELOAD: #1000
    reloading = False
```

I highly recommend putting 1000 into a variable (named `TIME_TO_RELOAD` or whatever you want), this will make it much easier to fine-tune and tweak the game constants.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! One note, I had to use `time.clock()` instead of `time.now()` because `clock()` will calculate how long the program runs for in seconds, while `now()` gives me the time of day. So now I want the the screen to display the ammo clip as full AFTER the reload is completed, not while reloading is taking place. Do you have any ideas on how this can be done? EDIT: Just kidding I figured it out :) Thanks for your help

Comment: And I apologize about the indentation in my code above, in my program it is formatted correctly but when I copy / pasted it I forgot to format it properly, sorry about that! It is now fixed :)

Comment: @Tanman1276 Okay cool, glad to hear that! Also, to get your ammo clip to display as full, you would just add whatever code you have to after the `reloading = False` line.